# Reading control from excel using smartxls api is not working

Tags: smartxls

I was trying to read form control from an excel file.
I am using smartXLS api.

In my excel file cell "c2" has list-box (formControl).
Now i want to read that that control .

I was tried with following code but it throws an exception

```
workBook.readXLSX("D:\\TestAssessment.xlsx");

//This row throws an exception.
//Here I was passed parameters in function as getFormControl(rowIndex,columnIndex)
FormControlShape fm = (FormControlShape)workBook.getFormControl(1, 2);
```

Can anyone know why it's throw an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read SmartXLS javaDoc.

```
FormControlShape shape = workBook.getFormControl(FormControlShape.ListBox, listBoxId);

// Here FormControlShape is inbuilt enum for to pass which type of form control you need to read/get.
// listBoxId is integer for index of the form control.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getFormControl(int type, int index) 
          get the specified index formcontrol from the current sheet
```

This is the javadoc of smartXLS describing the method. The parameter `int type` means the type of the form control; Types: 20-ComBox 11-CheckBox 18-ListBox. The parameter `int index` means the index of the form control.

Hope this can help you.